# Matrix continuous (x,y) path

Tags: matlab, geometry

I have an (x,y) matrix coordinates representing a path.

```
M=[2 2;2 1;1 1;3 1;3 2;3 3;2 3]
```

How can I transform it into matrix path beginning at the starting point (1,1) and ending at (3,1) so that:

```
M=[1 1;2 1;2 2;2 3;3 3;3 2;3 1]
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Perform DFS on the graph until all of the vertices are in the path (or you run out of possible paths).

Comment: Here's a DFS implementation for you, in case you need one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31979369/combining-pairs-in-a-string-matlab/31994782#31994782