# do image segmentation given the boundary of regions in the image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I get an image and also the boundary of regions in the image. For example, I have a mask with logical type, the value of boundary is 1, while for other pixels, the value is 0. I want to label the regions segmented by the boundaries, while I am not sure how to segment and label the region based on the continuous boundary.

The boundary looks like this:

```
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0
```

With the above diagram, there would be four regions that would be identified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function [`bwlabel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html) from the image processing toolbox is the ideal function you should use to label each continuous region of non-zero pixels in a binary mask.  However, you want to perform this on the **zero** pixels that are delineated by the "boundary" pixels that are set to 1.  Therefore, simply use the inverse of the binary mask so that you are operating on the zero pixels instead of the non-zero pixels.  Also from your definition, regions are separated using a 4 pixel connectivity.  `bwlabel` by default uses 8 pixel connectivity when searching for continuous regions, which means that it looks in the N, NE, E, SE, S, SW, W and NW directions.  You'll want to manually specify 4 pixel connectivity, which looks in only the directions of N, E, S and W.

Supposing your mask was stored in the variable `L`, simply do:

```
labels = bwlabel(~L, 4);
```

The output `labels` would be a map that tells you the membership of each pixel.  Regions of the same membership tells you that those pixels belong to the same group.

Using your example, we get:

```
>> L = [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 
        0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
        1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0
        0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0];
>> labels = bwlabel(~L, 4)

labels =

     1     1     1     0     3     3     3     0     4     4
     1     1     0     3     3     3     3     0     4     4
     0     0     2     0     3     3     3     0     4     4
     2     2     2     2     0     3     0     4     4     4
```

Each island of zeroes has a unique ID where pixels that belong to same ID belong to the same island or region.  If you don't want to use `bwlabel` and do this from first principles, you can refer to my previous post using Depth First Search to find regions of connected components: [How to find all connected components in a binary image in Matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26332883/how-to-find-all-connected-components-in-a-binary-image-in-matlab/26333226#26333226). Be advised that this is not efficient code and so you should only use it for educational and research purposes. Using `bwlabel` is recommended as it is a fast function and well tested.   You'll also have to modify the code so that it doesn't search in an 8 pixel connectivity and it should look at only a 4 pixel connectivity.  Make sure you also inverse the input before using the code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! While, my question is to label the connected components with value 0, not 1. So, in the example, there should be 4 labels for 4 regions. I think I can solve this by doing recursively, while not sure how it looks like. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Just perform the same procedure on the inverse of the image then. So call the function with `~L`. You will also need to specify 4 pixel connectivity. This way, the values that are 0 become the pixels of interest while the values of 1 separate those nonzero pixels. Is this what you're looking for? I'll be happy to edit my answer if this is the case. In fact, I believe this is the right answer for you judging by you saying there are 4 regions.

Comment: @user3919259 I've edited my post based on your comments. I believe this is what you want. Good luck.